# Can't make autolayout

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, interface-builder, autolayout

I'm trying to lay out six UIViews onto a UIViewController, but I can't make them appear correctly in the simulator. Could someone please explain what constraints to use here to make it appear the same on the simulator?

My desired result, as seen in interface builder:

[image]

My currently result:

[image]

I'm using storyboards, Xcode 6, iOS 8 and autolayout.

Thanks!

Comment: I had a very similar problem, I couldn't make it work with autolayout. But turns out the best solution (which adapted to any screen size) was to build a simple UICollectionView

Comment: @inorganik I see, that's a very clever solution. How did you go about populating the UICollectionView? Did you do it with Interface Builder (if possible) or did you do it with code?

Comment: It's fairly simple. Set the width and the height of the first rectangle and then  select equal widths and equal heights. Set up trailing, leading, top and bottom constraints and you are ready to go.

Comment: I'll add an answer below...

Answer (score 2):

You don't need collectionViews, nor any trickery in code. This is easily achievable in AutoLayout in interface builder. 
Btw, the number and type of constraints matters. You should keep it as common sense as possible so that you can maintain it, and keep their number to minimum for the compositing part of UI rendering to stay fast. My solution is thus less complex than @k6sandeep s.

1) Lay them all out evenly, select all 6 tiles by CMD+mouseclick and add these constraints.

[image]

2) select each tile individually and add a particular constraint as shown below.

[image]

They have the same size and "kiss" each other on all sides and main view.

Once done, interface builder will stop complaining about missing constraints and you will just recalculate frames to make it perfect.

Answer (score 1):

If you are only ever going to display 6 views a CollectionView might would not be necessary. You could place a 6 views with a constraints to pin the corner views to the respective corners. Then add constraints for the horizontal spacing between each neighbouring row/column. And finally set equal width and height constraints from the first (or any view) to the others. This does mean there are more views and constraints with dragging and dropping but you wont need to worry about populating a collectionView datasource and (perhaps the best bit) you won't need to write any code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple gif image of what I tried. It is actually fun to do this. You have to make sure that all have equal width and equal height, the views in rows have aligning top and bottom edges, while the views in columns have aligning leading and trailing edges. Then, if you set the distance between adjacent views and the edges to zero, it will all be done.

The image below shows what I actually mean in a pictorial representation.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and couldn't make it work with autolayout. Turns out a UICollectionView was perfect for this though.

For a 2 x 6 grid:

```
CGFloat screenWidth = [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.width;
CGFloat screenHeight = [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.height;
CGSize collectionSize = CGSizeMake(screenWidth, screenHeight);
CGFloat cellWidth = screenWidth / 2;
CGFloat cellHeight = (screenHeight - 44) / 3; // deduct title bar
CGSize cellSize = CGSizeMake(cellWidth, cellHeight);

CGPoint collectionPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0);
CGRect collectionFrame = {collectionPoint, collectionSize};

// set up collection view flow layout
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 0;
flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0;
flowLayout.itemSize = cellSize;
flowLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);

// instantiate
self.categoryCollectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:collectionFrame collectionViewLayout:flowLayout];
```

Then you can return the cell contents in

`- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

Make sure you implement other necessary delegate methods of UICollectionView like `numberOfItemsInSection`.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by this. Couldn't I create a UICollectionViewController, create 6 different UICollectionViewCells with XIB and use those?

Comment: If they are totally different you would drag out a UICollectionViewCell for each view and place it in the collection view controller, give them identifiers, then add UI elements to each one as needed. Otherwise you could reuse the same collection view cell, create a custom cell class, and just give it different contents in `collectionViewCellForItemAtIndexPath`. It works pretty much the same as a table view.